# Finding bar code from an image file

Tags: c#, barcode

I do have a set of image files. Some of the files contains a bar code and I want to separate those from others. In c# how to find the presence of a bar code in an image file??

Comment: I know this is quite old but still I've done a quite good example [here](https://github.com/SeppPenner/EmguCVZXingBarcodeExample)

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply some computer vision algorithms. You can develop them using OpenCV (via P/Invoke in C#), or EmguCV (http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which is .NET wrapper for OpenCV. There are also libraries made specific for barcode detection - ZXing comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

If the bar codes are located at fixed positions, you can simply save these areas from the images to separate images and process them. If you need to locate the barcodes in the first place, you can use EmguCV for pattern recognition.